Why is instantiating a variable slow in python?
The problem is Leetcode 2097.
Here is my code
class Solution:
    def validArrangement(self, pairs: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
        G = defaultdict(list)
        d = defaultdict(int)
        
        for x, y in pairs:
            G[x].append(y)
            d[x] += 1
            d[y] -= 1
        
        x = -1
        for k in d:
            if d[k] == 1:
                x = k
                break
        
        ans = []
        def dfs(v):
            while G[v]:
                dfs(G[v].pop())
            ans.append(v)
        
        dfs(x)
        ans.reverse()
        return [[ans[i], ans[i+1]] for i in range(len(ans)-1)]

This doesn't pass (time limit exceeded) but once I delete the line x=-1 right before the for loop (for k in d) it passes. Why is instantiating x=-1 too slow, also why does this work unlike other languages like C++ where the x=k alone without the x=-1 is a different namespace?

Presumably it's not x = -1 that's slow but calling dfs(-1)?

Oh, yes! The -1 is never in the list so unless there is a vertex with unequal out and in-degrees it would've ran on -1. Thanks!

But doesn't dfs(-1) return immediately?

@nocomment no because G[-1] returns the last element of G...

@Jean-BaptisteYunès No it doesn't. Do you think G is a list? It's not. And G[-1] returns an empty list. Which is false, so the while statement stops immediately.

@nocomment Oh stupid I am, it is a dict...

You get a wrong answer when you set x=-1 as it is possible that there is no node with outdegree - indegree = 1 (e.g. the whole graph being a loop). In this case, calling dfs(-1) immediately returns as -1 is not an actual node, so you get an empty list, which is incorrect.
When the whole graph is a loop, you can start from any node. When you do not have x=-1, the value of x comes from the last iteration of for x, y in pairs:, which is of course a valid node. This allows your code to work in that specific case too.
Alternatively, you can more explicitly assign x = pairs[0][0] as well.
